# How to write strongly typed generic extension function in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-methods, type-inference

Focus on the **strong** and **generic** parts.

Let's say I have this extension function:

```
fun <E> Collection<E>.myContains(item: E) : Boolean {
    // quite pointless, I know, but a simple example
    return item in this
}
```

the intention is to write a function that only accepts types of the collection elements (`E`), but this is not validated by the compiler?!

```
val isItInside: Boolean = listOf(1, 2).myContains("1")
```

happily compiles. My guess is that `E` is inferred to be `Any`.

**How can I enforce this restriction within the Kotlin type system/generics?**

(Kotlin version 1.3.41)

---

#### Original context

An exercise to try to write a small assertion framework. A bit more complicated, but tried to get the simplest repro above.

```
class Asserter<T>(val value: T)

infix fun <T> T.should(block: Asserter<T>.() -> Unit) =
    Asserter(this).block()

fun <T : Collection<*>> Asserter<T>.haveSize(size: Int) {
    check(this.value.size == size) {
        "expecting ${this.value} to be of size $size"
    }
}

fun <E, T : Collection<E>> Asserter<T>.contain(item: E) {
    check(item in this.value) {
        "$item does not exist in $item"
    }
}

class ShouldTest {

    @Test fun intList() {
        listOf(1, 2) should {
            haveSize(2)
            contain(1)
            contain("2") // this shouldn't compile
        }
    }

    @Test fun stringList() {
        listOf("1", "2") should {
            haveSize(2)
            contain(1) // this shouldn't compile
            contain("2")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (The question is clear from the first bit; I don't think the original context really adds much except bulk.  Would it be better in a link, or omitted?)

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be due to the variance on the `Collection` interface's parameter, which is defined as `Collection<out E>`.

This means that `Collection<Any>` is a supertype of `Collection<E>`, and so (apparently) the `Collection<Any>.myContains()` extension can be called on a `Collection<Int>`.

You can confirm this by replacing it with the invariant `MutableCollection` (and also the `listOf()` with `mutableListOf()`); you then get the compile-time ‘Type mismatch’ error as expected.

This surprised me, though.  I guess the compiler must infer `E` using *both* the receiver type and the parameter type.  (Can anyone confirm this?)  And, as you point out, it has the annoying effect of preventing stricter type-safety.

Comment: I wonder if having it as an upper bound (T@contain) in an invariant location (T@Asserter) makes any difference?! Probably not, because they behave the same way. Except the original context is more levels of inferred generics?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a solution:

```
class Asserter<in T>(val value: @UnsafeVariance T)
```

Comment: This doesn't make "this shouldn't compile" lines error :(