# How to restrict the generic extension function parameter type?

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-function

I try to use the list extension function binarySearch

```
public fun <T> List<T>.binarySearch(element: T, comparator: Comparator<in T>,
fromIndex: Int = 0, toIndex: Int = size): Int
```

This is my definition:

```
open class Z
open class ZZ : Z()
open class ZZZ : ZZ()
open class ZZZZ : ZZZ()

val list: List<ZZZZ> = listOf()
val a0 = list.binarySearch("text", stringComparator) <-- error
val a1 = list.binarySearch("text", anyComparator)
val a2 = list.binarySearch(Z(), zComparator)
val a3 = list.binarySearch(ZZ(), zzComparator)
val a4 = list.binarySearch(ZZZ(), zzzComparator)

val stringComparator = Comparator<String> { o1, o2 -> o1.length.compareTo(o2.length) }
val anyComparator = Comparator<Any> { o1, o2 -> o1.hashCode().compareTo(o2.hashCode()) }
val zComparator = Comparator<Z> { o1, o2 -> o1.hashCode().compareTo(o2.hashCode()) }
val zzComparator = Comparator<ZZ> { o1, o2 -> o1.hashCode().compareTo(o2.hashCode()) }
val zzzComparator = Comparator<ZZZ> { o1, o2 -> o1.hashCode().compareTo(o2.hashCode()) }
```

The function binarySearch can not accept the String type but can accept the supertype of ZZZZ. I think the first parameter only accept ZZZZ type because List < T > is defined, but why it can accept all the supertype of ZZZZ?

**UPDATE:**

I create a list extension function like this:

```
fun <T> List<T>.ccc(t: T): Boolean {
    return contains(t)
} 

val list = listOf<ZZZZ>()
list.ccc("Q")
list.ccc(0)
list.ccc(mutableListOf<String>())
list.ccc(Z())
list.ccc(ZZ())
list.ccc(ZZZ())
```

I found it can accept many kind of type, the related question like this:
[How to write strongly typed generic extension function in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57224118/how-to-write-strongly-typed-generic-extension-function-in-kotlin)

Is the `binarySearch()` function same as the `ccc()`?

Why `ccc()` can accept not only ZZZZ's supertype but also others?

Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

Because `List` is covariant, so a `List<ZZZZ>` is also a `List<Z>`, a `List<Any>` etc. So in cases `a1` to `a4` there is a suitable `T` which can be inferred and they compile.

If you *really* want to avoid it you could create an invariant wrapper

```
class InvariantList<T>(val x: List<T>)

public fun <T> InvariantList<T>.binarySearch(element: T, comparator: Comparator<in T>, fromIndex: Int = 0, toIndex: Int = size): Int = x.binarySearch(element, comparator, fromIndex, toIndex)

val list: InvariantList<ZZZZ> = InvariantList(listOf())
```

Now

```
val a0 = list.binarySearch("text", stringComparator)
val a1 = list.binarySearch("text", anyComparator)
val a2 = list.binarySearch(Z(), zComparator)
val a3 = list.binarySearch(ZZ(), zzComparator)
val a4 = list.binarySearch(ZZZ(), zzzComparator)
```

all will fail to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I update a  related question, can you help me to understand? Thanks!

Comment: Because List is covariant, I think the list only accept itself and it's subtype, isn't it?

Comment: I said the first line of your answer, "Because List is covariant,", so List<ZZZZ>  only can be the list<T> which T class extend ZZZZ, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Covariant means `List<B>` is subtype of `List<A>` when `B` is a subtype of `A`. So `List<some subtype of ZZZZ>` is subtype of `List<ZZZZ>`, not vice versa.